# What are the disadvantages when I use mutually dependent foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I know that it's not a good method to use two tables with mutual foreign key definitions, but I don't understand the difficulties that arise in the database.
An example: I've a table city and a table state. City.city points at state.capitalcity and state.state points at city.state.
I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you provide the example, and then we can tear it apart

Comment: Taking a guess here, possibly some circular logic where, for example, you cant delete from one table without deleting the other record at the same time.  Same goes other DML and DDL statements.  Give it a try and see what happens.

Comment: ok thank you! I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine.  The problem arises when the keys are `NOT NULL`.  In that case,

- You can't insert a new `state`, because the `capitalcity` needs to exist.
- Your can't insert a the `capitalcity`, because the state needs to exist.

Oops!  That makes it a little hard load *any* data at all.

Of course, you can get around this by dropping or delaying the foreign key constraints.

You don't have this issue if one or either of these is `NULL`able -- such as the `capitalcity`.